# How to reach the localhost of a unity game from android emulator

Tags: c#, php, android, unity-game-engine, emulation

I'm developing a game using Unity3d and I'm facing a problem. The game which is written in C# has a database that linked using PHP (XAMMP)..

But the issue: I tried to post my Ip address instead of Localhost in c# script but still I can't connect the db,,

I used both: `"http:MY_PC_IP:8080/insertuser.php";`
and: `"http:MY_PC_IP/insertuser.php";`
I'm using Nox as an emulator..

Comment: Try disabling your firewall

Comment: @Sagar It didn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the internal IP address `10.0.2.2`

Comment: Che k your firewall rules in your PC. Check Internet permissions in your Android manifest file. Instead of using plain IP use http://10.0.2.2. Note that local host and 127.0.0.1 won't work as it's only a poop back to the internal system

Comment: IN the XAMPP access logs does to show whether it was accessed by the emulator?

Comment: It does work finally on emulator , but when I press play on Unity now, it doesn;t work

Answer (score 0):

You need to use following command:

`adb reverse tcp:8080 tcp:8080`

And instead of using ip address use localhost